# Проблема с тревогой «Не является ответом»

Tags: поддержка, тревоги

#### 1. [Очистка экрана](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/14166/%D0%9E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0/14432#14432)

> clrscr();
>
> попробуйте

Автор просит не использовать `conio.h`. Функия `clrscr` как раз оттуда. Поставил тревогу «Не является ответом». Отклонили.

#### 2. Как выключить ч/б режим в Windows 10? (сообщения [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736381/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC-windows-10/807632#807632), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736381/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC-windows-10/801993#801993))

1. > Cочетание клавиш <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>windows</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>
2. > Windows+ctrl+c (включить цветовой фильтр)

Оба эти ответа **никак** не отличаются от уже принятого. Следовательно, они не несут *никакой* пользы, а значит их *стоит* удалить.

Возможно, модератора, смутила причина — «Не является ответом», т. к. формально оба эти сообщения *являются* ответами. Но:

> Сообщение было опубликовано в качестве ответа, но оно не содержит ответа на вопрос. Сообщение может быть правкой, комментарием, другим вопросом, но, возможно, его **стоит просто удалить**.

В таком случае, может, стоит добавить новую причину, что-то типа «Ответ не отличается от уже принятого»?

Comment: Мне как-то такую тревогу прокомментировали:   `отклонены - не следует использовать сигнал тревоги для неточных или не верных ответов. `, думаю этот случай как ваш. А вот вопрос последний я думаю надо вынести отдельным вопросом.

Comment: @VladSpirin, это одна из стандартных причин.

Comment: @Qwertiy я не спорю, согласен со всем :) И такие комментарии очень кстати, хорошо помогают ( когда тот кто реагирует на тревогу, хоть какие-то комментарии оставляет если отклоняет) У меня не на все были комменты, жаль.

Comment: стоит отличать плохие технически ответы от сообщений, которые вообще ответами не являются. Критерий простой: вы обязаны на 100% правильный выбор сделать практически не владея техническими знаниями по меткам вопроса. Что не является ответом: комментарии к вопросу, ответам, ссылки на возможные решения, новые вопросы (посмотрите на явные пункты в интерфейсе). Что является [плохим] ответом (может требовать знаний технических, чтобы "плохим" распознать): неверный ответ, копия другого ответа, любая честная попытка ответить на вопрос, которая не попадает в предыдущие категории (см. очередь проверок).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Автор просит не использовать conio.h. Функия clrscr как раз оттуда.

Ну, в принципе да. Но там ответ с рейтингом -1. Т. е. вроде как видно, что ответ не лучший. А некую полезную информацию он всё же несёт. Да и вообще, я предпочитаю не трогать совсем уж старые ответы, если для этого нет явных причин. А в данном случае их нет.

> Как выключить ч/б режим в Windows 10?

Да, во-первых, смущает название тревоги. Во-вторых, один из ответов содержит такой текст: *"(включить цветовой фильтр)"* - этого названия в принятом ответе нет, а оно может где-то пригодиться для поиска. Удалять данный ответ я причин не вижу. Как и минусовать, кстати. А другой сейчас удалил.

Comment: А насчет названия причины что скажете? Если сообщение является ответом, но его все-же *следует* удалить, то какую причину выбирать? «*Требуется вмешательство модератора*»?

Comment: @Eanmos эта самая дерзкая причина ) Пробовал в самый первый раз, по неопытности пользования ресурсом ))) У модераторов итак вагон работы.

Comment: @VladSpirin, всё равно все тревоги на комментариях приходят модераторам... Хотя стоп, тут не на комментарии. Что-то я запутался. Подозреваю, что тревоги на удаление тоже приходят...

Comment: Я знаю @Qwertiy я просто о том, что эта причина не подходит